# What is the name for the "nothing particle"?

Tags: terminology

What is the name for a particle with zero mass, zero charge, no strong force, no weak force and has no energy?

Comment: "Minus the photon"? The photon is the name of the particle that is created when electron and positron annihilate.

Comment: Even the field theoretical framework, there is no "nothing particle" created. If you like, you can call it "vacuum" if it makes you feel any better.

Comment: On annihilation, there are usually two photons created to satisfy conservation of momentum.

Comment: "the vacuum state"?

Comment: Nothingness.${}$

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing. Electron annihilation produces 2 or 3 photons. You are misunderstanding something.